# slow performace of select with function fn_decompress

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

SQL Server query result is on 40 GB database very slowly. `fn_decompress` function is probably called for decompression data for each LIKE statement (it is bad for performance).

My idea is call function for data decompression **only onetime for each row**, then save value to variable `@decompData` and compare .

```
SELECT  ID, CAST(dbo.fn_decompress(dbo.ApplLogG2MessagesDataXML.Data) AS nvarchar(MAX)) AS Data
FROM     dbo.ApplLogG2MessagesDataXML
WHERE  (CAST(dbo.fn_decompress(dbo.ApplLogG2MessagesDataXML.Data) AS nvarchar(MAX)) LIKE '%alfa@gmail.com%' OR
            CAST(dbo.fn_decompress(dbo.ApplLogG2MessagesDataXML.Data) AS nvarchar(MAX)) LIKE '%mitcherl@better.com%' OR
            CAST(dbo.fn_decompress(dbo.ApplLogG2MessagesDataXML.Data) AS nvarchar(MAX)) LIKE '%mismatch@woobie.net%' OR
            CAST(dbo.fn_decompress(dbo.ApplLogG2MessagesDataXML.Data) AS nvarchar(MAX)) LIKE '%kopii@lerhard.info%' OR
            CAST(dbo.fn_decompress(dbo.ApplLogG2MessagesDataXML.Data) AS nvarchar(MAX)) LIKE '%metablock@gmail.com%' OR
            CAST(dbo.fn_decompress(dbo.ApplLogG2MessagesDataXML.Data) AS nvarchar(MAX)) LIKE '%peter@och.fr%' OR
            CAST(dbo.fn_decompress(dbo.ApplLogG2MessagesDataXML.Data) AS nvarchar(MAX)) LIKE '%info@lepit.de%' OR
            CAST(dbo.fn_decompress(dbo.ApplLogG2MessagesDataXML.Data) AS nvarchar(MAX)) LIKE '%nimrod@gmail.com%' OR
            CAST(dbo.fn_decompress(dbo.ApplLogG2MessagesDataXML.Data) AS nvarchar(MAX)) LIKE '%janine.boecher@gmail.cz%' OR
            CAST(dbo.fn_decompress(dbo.ApplLogG2MessagesDataXML.Data) AS nvarchar(MAX)) LIKE '%lipican@ninestor.eu%' OR
            CAST(dbo.fn_decompress(dbo.ApplLogG2MessagesDataXML.Data) AS nvarchar(MAX)) LIKE '%lejby.fejby@auto.it%' OR
            CAST(dbo.fn_decompress(dbo.ApplLogG2MessagesDataXML.Data) AS nvarchar(MAX)) LIKE '%kamil@senemil.cz%' OR
            CAST(dbo.fn_decompress(dbo.ApplLogG2MessagesDataXML.Data) AS nvarchar(MAX)) LIKE '%mikahekinen@word.buz%')
```

my idea for better performance is:

```
    SELECT  ID, CAST(dbo.fn_decompress(dbo.ApplLogG2MessagesDataXML.Data) AS nvarchar(MAX)) AS Data
        FROM     dbo.ApplLogG2MessagesDataXML
        WHERE 
@decompData =  CAST(dbo.fn_decompress(dbo.ApplLogG2MessagesDataXML.Data) AS nvarchar(MAX))
@decompData LIKE '%alfa@gmail.com%' OR 
@decompData LIKE '%mitcherl@better.com%' OR
@decompData LIKE '%mismatch@woobie.net%' OR 
....next emails conditions LIKE
```

Comment: You have two problems, one is the compress and the other is the `LIKE '%%'` neither allow you use index so you have to scan all the 40gb. You probably should discard the compress and add INDEX or FULL TEXT search

Comment: Agreed with Juan - if query performance is important, stop optimizing for disk space.

Answer (score 0):

The point is you use the `CAST(dbo.fn_decompress(dbo.ApplLogG2MessagesDataXML.Data) AS nvarchar(MAX))` 14 times. Just declare it once in a subselection and use the alias in your where conditions.

Like That:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT  ID, CAST(dbo.fn_decompress(dbo.ApplLogG2MessagesDataXML.Data) AS nvarchar(MAX)) AS Data
    FROM dbo.ApplLogG2MessagesDataXML
) as innerTable
WHERE  (
    `Data` LIKE '%alfa@gmail.com%' OR
    `Data` LIKE '%mitcherl@better.com%' OR
    `Data` LIKE '%mismatch@woobie.net%' OR
    `Data` LIKE '%kopii@lerhard.info%' OR
    `Data` LIKE '%metablock@gmail.com%' OR
    `Data` LIKE '%peter@och.fr%' OR
    `Data` LIKE '%info@lepit.de%' OR
    `Data` LIKE '%nimrod@gmail.com%' OR
    `Data` LIKE '%janine.boecher@gmail.cz%' OR
    `Data` LIKE '%lipican@ninestor.eu%' OR
    `Data` LIKE '%lejby.fejby@auto.it%' OR
    `Data` LIKE '%kamil@senemil.cz%' OR
    `Data` LIKE '%mikahekinen@word.buz%'
)
```

The problem you caused with `CAST(dbo.fn_decompress(dbo.ApplLogG2MessagesDataXML.Data) AS nvarchar(MAX))` 14 times is that you recalculate 14 times the same Data. So your System needs to calculate 14 times your 40GB. That's not really performant.

Comment: RyffLe: yes exactly - 13x times in WHERE clausule the same Data. I know this. Use Alias as you notice is not in WHERE posible. Subquery is syntactic better, but it does not solve the performance problem.

Comment: Sorry I am a bit tired I gat to less sleep xD what ever I set the alias in a sub selection. should be work now. Probably test it and gave me a feedback if it is faster or slower.

Comment: SQL is declarative and SQL Server is free to inline that `CAST(...)` 14 times. You should look at the execution plan. It's possible SQL Server only calculated `CAST(...)` once in the first place.

Comment: The question wasn't about if the System can or not xD the question was about the performance ;)

Comment: I tried "Display Estimated Execution Plan" for:

A) my original code

- [Execution Plan A][https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIgoE.png]
 

B) recommended code by @Ryffle


     ) AS innerTable WHERE innerTable.Data LIKE '%alfa@gmail.com%' OR...

 

 - [Execution Plan B][https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YGno.png]

BUT - results of Execution plans A,B looks both the same :(

Comment: I gat one question, why do you do for example: `%mikahekinen@word.buz%` is there a possibility that there is something behind the Top-Level-Domain? I don't think so xD I mean the Root-Label is to 99% empty if it is filled it's a fake address.

Comment: If the execution plans look the same then it is likely that the planner is smart enough to only call the function once. Don't make assumptions about how it works - it's most likely not calling that function fourteen times

Comment: @RyffLe: emails addresses are fictional

Comment: Two more question from me. What input have your `fn_decompress` table and how fast is the Query running through your tables?

Comment: how long is your query taken and how long is mine taken? just for knowledge